# Injecting a module that contains an injected module using mef2

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, windows-services, mef

I have a windows service and I'm injecting a module to it:

```
private ICoupon _couponManager;
...
DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Plugins"));
_container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
_couponManager = _container.GetExportedValue<ICoupon>();// Here I'm getting an exception
```

But the module that I'm trying to import is an constructer injected module:

```
[Import(typeof(IWallet))]
private IWallet _iWallet;

private static CompositionContainer _container;

public CouponManager()
{
    DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Plugins"));
    _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
    _container.ComposeParts();
}
```

So I'm getting "An exception occurred while trying to create an instance of type 'X.Business.CouponManager'." error. How do I have to inject my module?

I'm not sure if my question is clear, if not please ask for details.

Thanks in advance,

Edit: The interesting part is: I can inject this module to my asp.net mvc application and use it without problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in addition to Gilles answer your class should look like this

```
[Export(typeof(ICoupon))]
public class CouponManager : ICoupon 
{
  private IWallet _iWallet;

  [ImportingConstructor]
  public CouponManager(IWallet iwallet)
  {
     this._iWallet= iwallet;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I'm still getting the same exception. Do you have any other insight?

Comment: debug your container before your call GetExportedValue. i assum that you just have the depencies from your plugin folder and you miss some dependencies from the app folder.

Comment: your container must have the ICoupon export and the IWallet export!

Comment: I disagree with the your class "should" look like this. While I think that ImportingConstructor is a better choice in most cases than using Import on properties, both are perfectly valid and will work under normal circumstances.

Comment: @Giles I guess this comes down to Constructor vs Property injection in terms hiding dependencies. I've found the use of Property injection, while it appears simpler, it does hide the requirements of your type. If you ignore the MEF/DI part for now and consider general use, if you weren't expressing dependencies through the constructor, how do others know what you need to provide to use the type correctly, and how can create an instance of your type in a *usable* state with just `new CouponManager()`?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is some business need I haven't grasped from your question, there is no need for CouponManager to have it's own CompositionContainer and for it to compose it's parts.

When you call

```
_couponManager = _container.GetExportedValue<ICoupon>();
```

It will compose an instance of your coupon manager. While doing so it will automatically compose all of it's imports (in this case, your IWallet) and then recursively compose all of their child imports.

Thus, if IWallet also has imports, they will also be composed in the initial call to

```
_couponManager = _container.GetExportedValue<ICoupon>();
```

So unless you need to have a seperate container for your wallet, I would remove the container in CouponManager and remove the composing in it's container.

Then I would try again to see if that resolves your exception.

Comment: I change my code regarding your suggestion but I'm still getting the same exception. Do you have any other insight?